# Android BiometricPrompt: Cannot resolve symbol PromptInfo

Tags: android, cannot-find-symbol, android-biometric-prompt

When I copied the following code from [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth) developer.android.com tutorial about adding biometric authentication in your android app:

```
BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo =
            new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
            .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
            .build();
```

PromptInfo is not recognized.

I have followed all the steps prior to this in the tutorial.

Comment: Do you add the dependency in your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to add this dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-rc01'
```

And make sure you use this import:

```
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
```

and **not**

```
import android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt;
```

Update: for the current version check: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.biometric/biometric?repo=google

Comment: I got 'implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-rc01"' and it didn't work, when changed to rc implementation it helped

Comment: The dependency is upgraded to -- 

implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha04'

Answer (score 0):

```
private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;
```

Add these dependencies in the app level gradle file :

```
 implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0"
 implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha05'
```